# How to translate window's coordinates into control coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get mouse position relatively to my listbox, in event handler i get window relative coordinates, how to translate it into control relative?

EDIT:

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    ...
}
```

So, it looks like it is mouse position i need, but really it could change for  the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `Mouse.GetPosition(RealitiveUIElement)` method

Here it is outlined on the MSDN Site
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition.aspx

```
// displayArea is a StackPanel and txtBoxMousePosition is 
// a TextBox used to display the position of the mouse pointer.
Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(displayArea);
txtBoxMousePosition.Text = "X: " + position.X +
    "\n" +
    "Y: " + position.Y;
```